# Is is possible to specify onEdit events like merging cells or deleting contents?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet with multiple sheets for projects. Each sheet is a broader project category or "bucket." I would like to have an overview sheet that automatically fills in project and bucket names when a new project is added to a bucket sheet. I think I'm pretty close at achieving this, but my current code adds to the Overview sheet when the edit is merging cells or deleting contents (so blank projects are added in Overview). It would be great if  would only add the project name to Overview when the cell started blank before the edit. It would be ideal if editing an existing project could change that project in Overview (if this can be done, it requires more thought and I can do that later. For now, I just need it to ignore when the event is merging or deleting contents).

If it's possible to specify different events, I think I could just add more if statements or conditions to exclude merging or deleting. This would be a usable fix. If it's possible to link the origin cell and the final cell for the project name, so that an edit to the original project cell would change the final project cell and vice versa, that would be amazing!

Here's my current code:

```
function onEdit(event) {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();

  var originTab = event.source.getActiveSheet();

  if(originTab.getName() != 'Overview' & originTab.getName() != 'Braindump'){
    var originCell = originTab.getActiveCell();

    if(originCell.getColumn() == 1){
      var projectName = originCell.getValue();
      var bucketName = originTab.getName();

      var finalTab = spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Overview'));

      var newRow = finalTab.getLastRow() + 1;

      finalTab.getRange("A" + newRow).setValue(bucketName);
      finalTab.getRange("B" + newRow).setValue(projectName);
    }
  }
}
```

This code does a great job of adding projects to the Overview sheet, but it also adds blank projects (still with the bucket name) when the edit is merging or deleting cell contents.

Edit: I've made a fix that works for me, but I would still like some input if anyone knows a better way! I just set it to delete a row in "Overview" if the project name cell is blank. So newest code is:

```
function onEdit(event) {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();

  var originTab = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var originTabName = originTab.getName()

  if(originTabName != 'Overview' & originTabName != 'Braindump'){
    var originCell = originTab.getActiveCell();

    if(originCell.getColumn() == 1){
      var projectName = originCell.getValue();
      var bucketName = originTab.getName();

      var finalTab = spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Overview'));

      var newRow = finalTab.getLastRow() + 1;

      finalTab.getRange("A" + newRow).setValue(bucketName);
      finalTab.getRange("B" + newRow).setValue(projectName);

      if(finalTab.getRange("B" + newRow).getValue() == ''){
        finalTab.deleteRow(newRow);
      }
    }
  }
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName(originTabName));
}
```

Comment: Seems like a question for the docs, rather than here.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var exshts=['Overview','Braindump']
  var sh=e.range.getSheet();
  var name=sh.getName()
  if(exshts.indexOf(name)>-1)return;
  if(e.range.columnStart==1) {
    var projectName=e.value;
    var fT=e.source.getSheetByName('Overview');
    var nrow=fT.getLastColumn() + 1;
    var fR1=fT.getRange(nrow,1);
    fR1.setValue(name);
    var fR2=fT.getRange(nrow,2);
    fR2.setValue(e.value);
    if(e.value=='')fT.deleteRow(nrow);
  }
}
```